# AssertionError after deleting the SSTable manually from cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0

I manually deleted few SSTables from cassandra due to space limitations. After that i am getting following error every time i execute `nodetool cfstats KEYSPACE.COLUMNFAMILY`. Why is it trying to find out the SSTable which i have deleted and giving AssertionError?

```
error: /mnt/cassandra2112/data/data/KEYSPACE/COLUMNFAMILY-3ef09530a70811e6ae4f97f9576f9b43/KEYSPACE-COLUMNFAMILY-ka-14-Data.db
    -- StackTrace --
    java.lang.AssertionError: /mnt/cassandra/data/data/KEYSPACE/COLUMNFAMILY-3ef09530a70811e6ae4f97f9576f9b43/KEYSPACE-COLUMNFAMILY-ka-14-Data.db
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.getApproximateKeyCount(SSTableReader.java:268)
        at org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ColumnFamilyMetrics$9.value(ColumnFamilyMetrics.java:296)
        at org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ColumnFamilyMetrics$9.value(ColumnFamilyMetrics.java:290)
        at com.yammer.metrics.reporting.JmxReporter$Gauge.getValue(JmxReporter.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.getAttribute(PerInterface.java:83)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.getAttribute(MBeanSupport.java:206)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:647)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1464)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getAttribute(RMIConnectionImpl.java:657)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that.

> Cassandra processes data at several stages on the write path, starting with the immediate logging of a write and ending in with a write of data to disk:
>
> - Logging data in the commit log
> - Writing data to the memtable
> - Flushing data from the memtable
> - Storing data on disk in SSTables

Memtables and SSTables are maintained per table. SSTables are immutable, not written to again after the memtable is flushed. Consequently, a partition is typically stored across multiple SSTable files.

That means you need SSTables to read data from the storage.

For further more information:
[How is data written in cassandra?](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataWritten.html)

Answer (score 0):

What if you go to your brother's car and remove one tire? The fact that he's not going to run with it in a highway doesn't imply he won't notice that a tire is missing.

---

### Short answer

Don't delete SSTables manually.

---

### Long anwer

A Cassandra table can be persisted on disk into **multiple** SSTables. They actually **are** your data, being them **live data**, or **deleted data** (yes, they are still **your data** and will be charged for them until a compaction occurs, and they are called tombstones!)

You probably deleted a "live" SSTable. The only thing you are able to delete without C* complaining about it are *snapshots*. And when you do, you need to use the [right tool](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/tools/toolsClearSnapShot.html).

If you are getting on low space then it's time to add one node to your cluster.

If you didn't expect to run out of space, it's time to go back and re-design your data model.

HTH.